# Ноw can I make 1) light colors glow / 2) warming image (CS5)

Tags: reverse-engineering, effect, tone

1. Ноw can I make light colors glow as in the example (I think it is done without the help of blur)
2. And how can I warm the image (I tried: 1) make layer- solid color, change blending options; 2) change color balance and use photo filter, but I can’t achieve such colors as in the example)
   [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you post the image you tried to edit with and without the edits you've made?

Comment: The only thing those images seems to have in common is heavy use of Photoshop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first image has a generic low contrast approach beginning with very soft lighting (overcast conditions) plus possible further adjustments (contrast reduction / mild soft focus effects). The colours have then undergone local modifications, the top part of the image has been tinted pink and the bottom tinted green this can be done most easily with adjustment layers and gradient masks.

The second image has either been through Photomatix or some other "HDR" processing, either from one exposure or many, or has had extensive use of fill light and the clarity slider in Lightroom. On top of that some colour adjustment has taken place, looks like split toning (or cross processing) whereby the highlights are tinted one way and the shadows another.

The bottom image has mixed lighting to begin with, possibly a bounced flash in addition to available light. Looks like a flash behind the subject also. Vignetting has been added in post as well as extensive skin smoothing.

Comment: Matt Grum, thanks a lot!!! Your answer caused a number of questions: 1) I started looking for articles about low contrast, there were several about black and white photography, and only one about colorful photo http://www.photographybyvarina.com/photography/quick-tips/focus-on-low-contrast-light  No information how I can achieve this low contast light, maybe someone can advise!   2) "highlights are tinted one way and the shadows another"... how can i do this? I tried to change Color Balance in Highlights anf shadows, but this method works very rough (with overexposure)

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you mean by glow, can you be more specific about which of your pictures you are referring to? If you mean the dress then the secret is in the lighting of the original shot mostly. However you can brighten highlights with the use of the Curve Adjustment Layer. (menu Layer > New Adjustment Layer > Curves...)

EDIT: I found this tutorial on High Key Glow: http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-effects/high-key-glow/ I'm guessing this might be what you are looking for.

But here is an answer to the other part of your question;

For the warming effect there are so called Adjustment Layers, one of those layers is the Photo Filter, with which you can add a Warming filter just like the ones used on the physical camera. Use the menu "Layer > New Adjustment Layer > Photo Filter..."